# Android Stock Email App doesn't want to work with pop3 server

Tags: java, android, email, pop3

I've been working on a pop3 server to compliment the smtp server i wrote recently in java, but when i tried to hook it up to the stock android email app (on samsung g s3 if that makes any difference) it will do the following commands:

CAPA

to which my server replies

+OK Capability list as follows \r\n

USER \r\n

UIDL \r\n

. \r\n

Then after that it goes through logging in with the username and pass

USER [username] \r\n

PASS [password omitted] \r\n

It's this point that it starts to act very weird.
The email app issues the 'STAT' command to which my server replies how it should as per the specification for POP3:

+OK 1 300 \r\n

However, after this, it hangs completely and the only thing recieved on the end of the server is 'NULL' etc till the server closes. Anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: Also, after scrutinizing logcat with my phone plugged in and email debugging on, it doesn't look like it's splitting out any exceptions

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you're not sending CR+LF as the spec says (and you seem to do otherwise), but only CR for that reply...?

Comment: that was a mistake on my part writing this question, I accidently left out part of it, this is the actual thing doing `this.os.writeBytes("+OK " + nummail + " " + "300" + CRLF);` Where os is an outputstream to the client, and nummail is 1, in this case, and crlf is `private final String CRLF = "\r\n";`

Comment: Are you listening to the actual network to see what is sent so that no buffering is taking place and your data isn't actually sent? (ie missing `Flush()` somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found what was causing it. I had two outputs on the password because I didn't read the specification close enough.. It's fixed now :)